# SQLite foreign key mismatch

Tags: sql, sqlite, foreign-keys, mismatch

I have 2 tables on a SQLite database

```
CREATE TABLE [Stores] (
  [ID] NVARCHAR(50), 
  [Description] NVARCHAR(255), 
  [GUID] CHAR(36), 
  [Created] DATETIME, 
  [Modified] DATETIME, 
  [Integrated] DATETIME, 
  CONSTRAINT [] PRIMARY KEY ([ID]));

CREATE TABLE [PriceDef] (
  [PriceNumber] INTEGER, 
  [Store] NVARCHAR(50) REFERENCES [Stores]([ID]) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE, 
  [Description] NVARCHAR(50), 
  [Margin] DECIMAL, 
  [GUID] CHAR(36), 
  [Created] DATETIME, 
  [Modified] DATETIME, 
  [Integrated] DATETIME, 
  CONSTRAINT [] PRIMARY KEY ([PriceNumber], [Store]));
```

When I try to delete a line in the Stores table I receive an exception with this message : foreign key mismatch, at this moment I only have this foreign key to the table Stores.

Please help :(

Thanks in advance
  Pedro Simões.

Thanks to Mitch,Yar and Tim for theirs answers/comments, in fact a lot of time as passed and my application is in a much more advanced state, the problem was solved like Tim said, all entities are enabled/disabled so I don't need any more to delete things.

Comment: I never, never use CASCADE DELETE...

Comment: @Mitch Wheat: That's not the point, but in this case I don't want to have a PriceDef without the corresponding Store, so they are logical related and I also warn the user before deleting, the problem here is that it doesn't work and I don't know why, everithing seems fine.

Comment: I realise that. I'm just making an observation. Take it or leave it....

Comment: @Mitch: No stress ;) I will take your advice, the problem is precisely the "On Delete Cascade", I think it's a bug on SQLite because everything seems fine, but since I have to retreive the related records, delete them after user confirmation it's only 1 line of code, no big deal. :)

Comment: I have an exactly same problem. Have you solved it?

Comment: @Pedro: I will see Mitch and raise him one in the referential integrity poker game: I never delete anything unless it's absolutely a mistake and the row is referenced nowhere else. Instead I "expire" entities. In that way it's possible to rerun historical/point-in-time reports, while being able to exclude rows if their expiryDate is <= today. Also, a primary key whose value can mutate gives me the heebie-jeebies. I think the problem here may be that the (composite) PK constraint and the FK constraint both reference [store].

Answer (score 2):

As I wrote in my comment: I just had a similar problem.

The problem was in **some other column foreign key constraint in the child table** not in "on delete cascade" itself.

In your case: are you sure that one of your tables (most likely the child one) does not take part in some other foreign key constraints?

Looks like SQLite checks all constraints when firing up one of them. It is actually mentioned in the documentation. DDL versus DML constraint checks.